# AutoCAD 2017 for Ubuntu

Tags: wine, gnome-terminal, directory, cad

How do I install AutoCAD 2017 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

I installed Wine and got the `.exe` in Desktop. I right clicked and selected Wine Windows Program Loader and nothing happened.

How do I properly install this software?
Also can it be done in Terminal? What specifically do I type? I tried
`wine AutoCAD_2017_English_Win_32_64bit_Trial_en-us_Setup_webinstall.exe`
but this returns `wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\AutoCAD_2017_English_Win_32_64bit_Trial_en-us_Setup_webinstall.exe"`

I noticed the location was off so I tried `wine /home/user/Desktop/AutoCAD_2017_English_Win_32_64bit_Trial_en-us_Setup_webinstall.exe` but nothing happens and the command prompt `$` returns.

Comment: WINE isn't the be-all-end-all Windows program runner. In most cases, it just doesn't work. I think this is one of those cases.

Comment: Check out <https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=86>. The results don't look very good. You might look into VirtualBox running a Windows guest OS. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema: You broke the [Wine App DB link](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=86).

Comment: There is no entry for AutoCAD 2017 in WIneHQ, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can use AutoCAD is through VirtualBox.

I made [a small tutorial in Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/106882842682420321979/posts/JPnwcUF4MgB)

**This instructions are for AutoCAD 2012, but it should be similar to newer versions as well.**

**Option 1**

Install Windows XP or 7 (no updates) and removed a few default applications and animations to make it very light on VirtualBox. Install AutoCAD and then select Seamless on VBox. Bingo!

Set up Vbox to use only 1.5 gb of ram and it works super fast. No delays no crashes.

Now I can copy the Windows XP/7 folder from my Vbox drive and distributed to other machines.

Your machine needs at least 6gb+ of ram. I have 8gb and with Vbox/Autocad open it uses a bit less than 3gb of ram.

**Option 2**

This takes some time to get it running. A few days ago I made [a tutorial in Spanish on how to use the Android AutoCAD version](http://proyectosbeta.net/2016/10/como-instalar-el-app-de-autocad-360-de-android-en-ubuntu-16-04/) on Ubuntu. It is much faster but with less features.

**Option 3**

Alternatively you can use [Bricscad](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/), a really good alternative to AutoCAD and it cost one third of the price.

Or you can try [Draftsight](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/), free but I never had good luck with performance. I guess it doesn't support all graphics card.

Answer (score -1):

Wine doesn't work with all applications.
You could use terminal only if you downloaded a version designed for Ubuntu, not a windows version.
As far as I know, AutoCAD doesn't support Ubuntu yet.